# Why are wizards poor in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

What's to stop the Weasleys from simply creating money? Can't they create gold, silver, or bronze? Why not make muggle money and exchange it at Gringotts? Old clothes? Or just use a doubling charm when purchasing an item for infinite "new" clothes?

Comment: Also quite dupey; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59278/why-cant-you-just-duplicate-money-in-the-harry-potter-series

Comment: Not as close, but still a dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9213/how-important-is-money-in-the-wizarding-world